# How to choose transistor for TTL

Tags: transistors, ttl

[image]

I have the following circuit, where logical zero = 0.2 V and logical one = 5.2 V. I chose KT301 (Soviet transistor) for it, but there is no such transistor in "electronic workbench" for simulation. What alternatives can I pick to simulate my circuit ?

Comment: Which transistor are you talking about? The one with tree emitters? I don't think you can find that as a discrete part. TTL ICs are different matter, obviously.

Comment: I'm talking about VT2 , VT3 and VT4

Comment: Are trying to simulate some specific IC or you just want a simulation (in whatever "Workbench" is [NI Multisim I suppose]) of a generic TTL gate?

Comment: Since it's an abstract exercise anyway, try any generic small transistor model and see what happens.

Comment: Are you trying to simulate some Soviet TTL circuit? KT301 seems to be a Soviet transistor: http://alltransistors.com/transistor.php?transistor=38507

Comment: @RespawnedFluff yes, it is Soviet transistor, I just wanted to find the alternative for KT301 to simulate circuit..

Comment: Ok, then edit your question to make it clear what your real goal is. It might get reopened that way.

Answer (score 1):

These are fabricated transistors on a silicon wafer and are not "known" by their indivual characteristics because they are not testable or provable as individual entities.

You might find some information from a manufacturer about these things but generally I think you may be searching for a needle in a haystack.